# How to assign responses to requests when doing multiple requests with jQuery $.when?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery `$.when` in order to process the results of multiple GET requests after all requests are done. Everything works well, but I want to assign 
each response to a specific ID that is part of the request URL.

How could I do this?

Unfortunately I can not change the web service to provide the ID in the response.

```
var requestList = [
    $.get("../webservice?customerId=" + 223),
    $.get("../webservice?customerId=" + 242),
    $.get("../webservice?customerId=" + 112)
];

var defer = $.when.apply($, requestList);
defer.done(function () {
    $.each(arguments, function (index, responseData) {
        // Here I need to find out the customerId of the response
        console.log("Result for customer ID " + customerId + " is: "+ responseData);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You could add customerId in your webservice response?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible, because I have no control over the service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap request with a function

```
function loadCustomer(customerId) {
    return $
            .get("../webservice?customerId=" + customerId)
            .then(function (data) {
               return {customerId: customerId, data: data};
            });
}
```

and use it like this

```
var requestList = [232, 3232].map(loadCustomer);

$.when.apply($, requestList).done(function() {
   $.each(arguments, function(_, data) {
       console.log("Result for customer ID " + data.customerId + " is: "+ data.data);
   });
});
```

Or you could modify incomming data and add `customerId`

```
function loadCustomer(customerId) {
    return $
            .get("../webservice?customerId=" + customerId)
            .then(function (data) {
               data.customeerId = customerId;
               return data;
            });
}
```

**UPD** as @Alnitak has mentioned. If you need additional arguments passed by `$.ajax` you could add them to the return object as well in whatever format you need.

Comment: Yup, using `.then()` is the right approach, although you should perhaps ensure that the additional two parameters get returned, too?

Comment: @Alnitak That's why there is `$.when`. It acts almost like `Promise.all` and returns a new promise that resolves when ALL deferreds are and rejects as soon as ANY original does.

Comment: I am *very* aware of that, and you've missed my point.  If you want to preserve `$.get()` semantics with `$.when` your `.then` should read: `.then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { data.customerId = customerID; return [ data, textStatus, jqXHR ]; } )`

Comment: Ohh, you mean awful jquery team idea to return multiple values from promise, breaking the very idea of what the promise is... :)

Comment: Umm, well, yeah, there is that :p